# dplyr: How does bind_rows() change the original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

hth1 is a data frame that I already have.

```
> hth1
Source: local data frame [13 x 14]
Groups: team [13]

    team   CSK    DC    DD    GL   KKR   KTK  KXIP    MI    PW   RCB  RPSG
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    CSK     0     8    11     0    11     2     9    10     4    10     0
2     DC     2     0     8     0     2     1     7     5     3     8     0
3     DD     5     3     0     0     7     2     8     5     2    10     2
4     GL     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
5    KKR     5     7    10     2     0     0     5    10     3    15     0
6    KTK     0     0     0     0     2     0     1     0     1     2     0
7   KXIP     8     3    10     2    14     0     0    11     2     6     1
8     MI    12     5    13     2     8     1     7     0     3    11     1
9     PW     2     1     4     0     2     0     4     3     0     1     0
10   RCB     9     3     7     2     3     0    12     8     4     0     1
11  RPSG     0     0     0     2     2     0     1     1     0     1     0
12    RR     8     2     7     0    14     1     7     6     2     7     0
13    SH     3     0     4     0     5     0     4     5     2     5     2
# ... with 2 more variables: RR <dbl>, SH <dbl>
```

Why do the data frame returned by bind_rows() and the original data frame differ?

```
> h <- list(hth1)
> hth_b1 <- bind_rows(h)
> identical(hth1, hth_b1)
[1] FALSE
> class(hth_b1)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(hth1)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> setequal(hth1, hth_b1)
TRUE
> anti_join(hth1, hth_b1)
Joining, by = c("team", "CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH")
Source: local data frame [0 x 14]
Groups: team [13]

# ... with 14 variables: team <chr>, CSK <dbl>, DC <dbl>, DD <dbl>, GL <dbl>,
#   KKR <dbl>, KTK <dbl>, KXIP <dbl>, MI <dbl>, PW <dbl>, RCB <dbl>,
#   RPSG <dbl>, RR <dbl>, SH <dbl>
```

What am I missing? I have been stuck here for a long time.

### Update 1:

As requested by Benjamin, I dput() function on both dataframes. Here is the output.

```
> dput(hth_b1)
structure(list(team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", 
"KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH"), CSK = c(0, 2, 
5, 0, 5, 0, 8, 12, 2, 9, 0, 8, 3), DC = c(8, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 3, 
5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0), DD = c(11, 8, 0, 2, 10, 0, 10, 13, 4, 7, 0, 
7, 4), GL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0), KKR = c(11, 
2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 14, 8, 2, 3, 2, 14, 5), KTK = c(2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), KXIP = c(9, 7, 8, 0, 5, 1, 0, 7, 4, 
12, 1, 7, 4), MI = c(10, 5, 5, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 3, 8, 1, 6, 5
), PW = c(4, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2), RCB = c(10, 
8, 10, 1, 15, 2, 6, 11, 1, 0, 1, 7, 5), RPSG = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2), RR = c(9, 7, 9, 0, 1, 1, 8, 10, 3, 
9, 0, 0, 7), SH = c(3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("team", 
"CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", 
"RPSG", "RR", "SH"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(team), indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", 
    "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH")), row.names = c(NA, -13L
), class = "data.frame", vars = list(team), .Names = "team"))
> 
> dput(hth1)
structure(list(team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", 
"KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH"), CSK = c(0, 2, 
5, 0, 5, 0, 8, 12, 2, 9, 0, 8, 3), DC = c(8, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 3, 
5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0), DD = c(11, 8, 0, 2, 10, 0, 10, 13, 4, 7, 0, 
7, 4), GL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0), KKR = c(11, 
2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 14, 8, 2, 3, 2, 14, 5), KTK = c(2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), KXIP = c(9, 7, 8, 0, 5, 1, 0, 7, 4, 
12, 1, 7, 4), MI = c(10, 5, 5, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 3, 8, 1, 6, 5
), PW = c(4, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2), RCB = c(10, 
8, 10, 1, 15, 2, 6, 11, 1, 0, 1, 7, 5), RPSG = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2), RR = c(9, 7, 9, 0, 1, 1, 8, 10, 3, 
9, 0, 0, 7), SH = c(3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("team", 
"CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", 
"RPSG", "RR", "SH"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), vars = list(team), labels = structure(list(
    team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", 
    "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), vars = list(team), drop = TRUE, .Names = "team"), indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L)
```

There is a difference in the output for both of them, there is an extra drop = TRUE for hth1.

I don't understand why it is not there in the other one.

Comment: could you run `dput(hth1)` and copy the output into your question?

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, there is a marginal difference in the output, could you kindly explain what is happening there?

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)    
test1 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)    
test2 <- bind_rows(list(test1))

identical(test1, test2) #FALSE
all_equal(test1, test2) #TRUE
```

You can check both their `attributes` and you can see the rownames differ:

```
rownames(test1)
```

> ```
>  [1] "Mazda RX4"           "Mazda RX4 Wag"       "Datsun 710"         
>  [4] "Hornet 4 Drive"      "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"            
>  [7] "Duster 360"          "Merc 240D"           "Merc 230"           
> [10] "Merc 280"            "Merc 280C"           "Merc 450SE"         
> [13] "Merc 450SL"          "Merc 450SLC"         "Cadillac Fleetwood" 
> [16] "Lincoln Continental" "Chrysler Imperial"   "Fiat 128"           
> [19] "Honda Civic"         "Toyota Corolla"      "Toyota Corona"      
> [22] "Dodge Challenger"    "AMC Javelin"         "Camaro Z28"         
> [25] "Pontiac Firebird"    "Fiat X1-9"           "Porsche 914-2"      
> [28] "Lotus Europa"        "Ford Pantera L"      "Ferrari Dino"       
> [31] "Maserati Bora"       "Volvo 142E"
> ```

```
rownames(test2)
```

> ```
>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"
> [14] "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26"
> [27] "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32"
> ```

Never expect tibbles to treat your rownames with respect, they may be silently dropped at any time.

Comment: I am getting the same result for checking rownames, > `rownames(hth1)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"
> rownames(hth_b1)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"`

Comment: Well that can happen without a reproducible example. Check the other attributes, and check with `all_equal`.

Comment: the output for all_equal is true, so does this means that all the values in both dataframes are in the exact order? > `all_equal(hth1, hth_b1)
[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the formatting on this answer, but it would appear that you have labels attached to one object, and not in the other.  Where the labels got attached or removed isn't something I can know without looking at code that generates the objects.  I've bolded the difference in your objects below.

*Note: not formatting this as code is a deliberate choice.  Formatting as code prevents me from marking the difference in the structure in bold text*

dput(hth_b1)
structure(list(team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", 
"KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH"), CSK = c(0, 2, 
5, 0, 5, 0, 8, 12, 2, 9, 0, 8, 3), DC = c(8, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 3, 
5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0), DD = c(11, 8, 0, 2, 10, 0, 10, 13, 4, 7, 0, 
7, 4), GL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0), KKR = c(11, 
2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 14, 8, 2, 3, 2, 14, 5), KTK = c(2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), KXIP = c(9, 7, 8, 0, 5, 1, 0, 7, 4, 
12, 1, 7, 4), MI = c(10, 5, 5, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 3, 8, 1, 6, 5
), PW = c(4, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2), RCB = c(10, 
8, 10, 1, 15, 2, 6, 11, 1, 0, 1, 7, 5), RPSG = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2), RR = c(9, 7, 9, 0, 1, 1, 8, 10, 3, 
9, 0, 0, 7), SH = c(3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("team", 
"CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", 
"RPSG", "RR", "SH"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(team), indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L **, labels = structure(list(
    team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", 
    "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH")), row.names = c(NA, -13L
), class = "data.frame", vars = list(team), .Names = "team"**))

dput(hth1)
structure(list(team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", 
"KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH"), CSK = c(0, 2, 
5, 0, 5, 0, 8, 12, 2, 9, 0, 8, 3), DC = c(8, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 3, 
5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0), DD = c(11, 8, 0, 2, 10, 0, 10, 13, 4, 7, 0, 
7, 4), GL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0), KKR = c(11, 
2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 14, 8, 2, 3, 2, 14, 5), KTK = c(2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), KXIP = c(9, 7, 8, 0, 5, 1, 0, 7, 4, 
12, 1, 7, 4), MI = c(10, 5, 5, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 3, 8, 1, 6, 5
), PW = c(4, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2), RCB = c(10, 
8, 10, 1, 15, 2, 6, 11, 1, 0, 1, 7, 5), RPSG = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2), RR = c(9, 7, 9, 0, 1, 1, 8, 10, 3, 
9, 0, 0, 7), SH = c(3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("team", 
"CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", 
"RPSG", "RR", "SH"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), vars = list(team), labels = structure(list(
    team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", 
    "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), vars = list(team), drop = TRUE, .Names = "team"), indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L)

In the example below, I will add labels to the `mtcars` data frame, then run it through `bind_rows`, and you'll see that the labels are no longer present.  This is what I believe is happening to your data.

```
library(Hmisc)
mtcars2 <- mtcars
label(mtcars2, self = FALSE) <- toupper(names(mtcars))

library(dplyr)

mtcars3 <- bind_rows(mtcars2)

identical(mtcars2, mtcars3)

label(mtcars3)
```

Comment: drop = TRUE makes the labels detached or removed in hth1?
`labels = structure(list( team = c("CSK", "DC", "DD", "GL", "KKR", "KTK", "KXIP", "MI", "PW", "RCB", "RPSG", "RR", "SH")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L), vars = list(team), drop = TRUE, .Names = "team"), indices = list( 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L)`

Comment: I think it's actually `bind_rows` that is dropping the label attribute.  Adding a reproducible example now.